How to delete range of columns by first and last names in the range?
I can specify a range of columns in data.table using: first_col:last_col and can subset the data.table using that syntax. But if I want to set the same columns to NULL, data.table says it can't 'find' the columns (see below).
Why is that?  And how can I delete a range of columns using "first_col:last_col" syntax?
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9)
#        a     b     c
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1:     1     4     7
# 2:     2     5     8
# 3:     3     6     9

d[, b:c ]
#        b     c
#    <int> <int>
# 1:     4     7
# 2:     5     8
# 3:     6     9

d[, b:c := NULL ]
#Error in eval(lhs, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : object 'b' not found


Here is using .SDcols:
dt[, names(.SD) := NULL, .SDcols = b:c ]

Relevant GitHub issue #6170

You can get the names with direct selection and then set them to NULL:
d[, names(d[, b:c]) := NULL]


That's a nice solution.  I'm not a programmer so I'm still stuck on why "b:c" is OK in d[,b:c] but not d[,b:c := NULL], but it must make sense to someone.  But thanks.  I think your solution is as concise as it can get.

You can try the following code, which creates a vector of the columns you need to assign to NULL.
myvars <- names(d)[do.call(seq, as.list(which(names(d) %in% c("b", "c"))))]
myvars
[1] "b" "c"

d[, (myvars) := NULL]
d
       a
   <int>
1:     1
2:     2
3:     3


Alternatively, you can use .SDcols
d[, names(d[, .SD, .SDcols = b:c]) := NULL]
d
       a
   <int>
1:     1
2:     2
3:     3


Your second option looks pretty good, but still not quite as concise as I would like.  I also realized after I posted that this seems to work too:  d[,-(b:c)]  but it's not intuitive to me, at least, because I'm so used to deleting columns by assigning NULL

Yes, me too! I rarely use data.table, so I was looking to use assignment here. Your answer is very concise.

You should probably answer your own question with that and accept it so others can learn.
